# Change class based on content of child span

Tags: jquery

```
<h3>
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus first"></span>
   <div class="asseticon ma">
      <div class="stateicon green">
      </div>
   </div>
   TEXT HERE
</h3>

<div class="accordion">

<h3>
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus second"></span>
   <div class="asseticon ma">
      <div class="stateicon green">
      </div>
   </div>
</h3>

</div>

<h3>
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus first"></span>
   <div class="asseticon ma">
      <div class="stateicon green">
      </div>
   </div>
   TEXT HERE
</h3>

<div class="accordion">

<h3>
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus second"></span>
   <div class="asseticon ma">
      <div class="stateicon green">
      </div>
   </div>
</h3>

</div>

<h3>
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus first"></span>
   <div class="asseticon ma">
      <div class="stateicon green">
      </div>
   </div>
   TEXT HERE
</h3>

<div class="accordion">

<h3>
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus second"></span>
   <div class="asseticon ma">
      <div class="stateicon green">
      </div>
   </div>
</h3>

</div>
```

I am looking for a jquery function that checks to see if the id of SECOND exists, and if it does, replace one of the classes of FIRST. Here is what I have so far but it's not working as intended.

Please note that there are multiple h3's and I need to iterate through each of these.

```
if($("span#first").children().length > 0) {
  $(this).removeClass('glyphicon')
         .removeClass('glyphicon-plus')
         .addClass('glyphicon-none');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how about something like this:

```
$("#second").length && $('#first').toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-plus glyphicon-none');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if( $("#second").length )
{
  $("#first").removeClass('glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-plus').addClass('glyphicon-none');
}//#second check
```

Comment: I apologize, what if there are multiple h3's and I have to iterate through all of them?

Comment: First of all, you need to modify your code, so that multiple h3's do not contain repeated id's. `id` must never be repeated on same page.

Comment: Yeah the spans have duplicate id's. I am just using this template as an example to help iterate through this code. I can just substitute the id as another attribute in the jquery.

Comment: there i changed the id to a class

Comment: there are multiple h3's and each contains both #second and #first? or one h3 contains #first, second contains #second, then again #first?